# iPhone: Creating a roll effect in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have the following function that moves a UIView from one side of the screen to the next:

```
-(void)animateView:(UIView *)p_view {

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];

    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(p_view.frame.origin.x - p_view.frame.size.width)] ;
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width];
    animation.duration = 0.8;
    animation.autoreverses = NO;
    animation.beginTime = 0; // ignore delay time for now
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [p_view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"horizontal_animation"];
}
```

now I wish to add a roll effect (a 2D soccer ball rolling on the screen)

1. how can I create a method to be called on each iteration so i can rotate the image?
2. is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 0):

You want to map your image onto the surface of a sphere and have it rotate across the screen? That's quite complex. You'll need to use OpenGL and texture mapping. You'd create an approximation of a sphere as a grid of points and map the image(s) you want to display to a texture that you'd draw onto the surface.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I wanted by adding another CABasicAnimation that rotates and when both together work with the same duration its the result I was looking for.

```
CABasicAnimation* animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];//@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation2.duration = 3;
animation2.repeatCount = 0.5;//INFINITY;
[p_view.layer addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```